# Exporting a database in phpmyadmin fails (localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

When I try to export a database sql file in phpmyadmin it fails. I get the following error: "Your output is incomplete, due to a low execution time limit on PHP level" .

I don't know what to do..

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Did you try configuring php.ini ?

Comment: better solution is to use mysql commandline. otherwise you have to increase `memory_limit` in your php.ini

Comment: Yes I'm sorry i had to mention it. I use Windows 10.

Comment: Ok, and are you using a web server like  Xampp or Wamp ?

Comment: @DevMan No not yet, but you mean Max_execution_time? what value do i have to give it?

Comment: I use Wamp, I tried to export a magento database

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I experienced the exact  problem already. According to comments *(windows, wamp, mysql)*, here is a solution to get an export of your database/table(s):

Open CMD and paste this:

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.5.8\bin
```

If your windows is installed into C drive, Then apply your own information in this line and paste it too:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql
```

**Note:** `username` is `root` by default.

---

Also you can determine a particular table like following:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename tablename1 tablename2 > filename.sql
```

---

Here is an example:

1. Open CMD
2. write `cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.5.8\bin`
3. Then write `mysqldump -u root -p univercity students > H://TheNameOfStudents.sql`

Comment: If you are using XAMPP or MAMP, another place to look for resource limits is in a file called "config.default.php" -- look for a var called $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] and increase or set to zero.

Comment: @LorienBrune : I am connecting to remote sever through xampp's phpmyadmin and your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin is a php application. (I should change my username to Obviousman.)

It's running out of time exporting your table.

You need to change a line in the file called `php.ini`.

If you're running WAMP on your own Windows box, you might find it at a path like `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`. But you have to look for it.

If you're using a hosting service, use their knowledge base or call their support and ask how to change php.ini.

look for the line called `max_execution_time`, and make its value bigger.

Comment: Unless this is CGI interfaced PHP, a restart of php-fpm or Apache will be required for the changes to take effect. If this is a hosted, shared environment, the providers may be unwilling to do that. The reason PHP execution time is normally limited is to prevent runaway resource consumption. A more practical approach would be to override the value in htaccess (if possible) at the top directory of the pma installation or inject `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of phpmyadmin/index.php